# MongoYii and sort using MongoRegex

Tags: php, mongodb, yii, yii-extensions

I am using MongoYii extension  and trying to sort using MongoRegex.However the below code throwing an exception "EMongoCriteria and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "sort". "

Please help me to sort out this issue. Advance thank you.

```
$criteria = new EMongoCriteria;
$criteria->sort(array('_id'=> new MongoRegex($regex)));
    return new EMongoDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
    'criteria' => $criteria,
));
```

Comment: Sort is a property of CDbCriteria not a method.

Comment: Use like this $criteria->sort(array('_id' => EMongoCriteria::SORT_ASC))

Comment: this geting error Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'SORT_ASC'